# Counting how many times an element in one dataset is found in another

Tags: r, count

I've been struggling with this problem in R. Basically, I've taken a subset of cities with flights that had a delay due to a carrier, and I need to figure out the total number of flights those cities had (delay or no delay). I can get the total number of flights per city pretty easily with:

```
count(flights, ORIGIN_CITY_NAME)
```

but I can't match that up to my data frame since they won't have the same number of rows. How can I filter that list so it only includes cities found in carrierDelayed?

```
require("dplyr")

flights <- read.csv("airplaneData.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

carrierDelayed <- subset(flights, flights$CARRIER_DELAY > 0)

carrierPercent <- data.frame(unique(carrierDelayed$ORIGIN_CITY_NAME), /* Total Count Should Go Here */)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read how to provide [minimal examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [reproducible question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), then come back and edit your question appropriately.

Comment: did you try `c1 %in% c2` or `?intersect`

Comment: Try: `merge() %>% filter() %>% group_by() %>% summarise(n())`.

Comment: `table(carrierDelayed$ORIGIN_CITY_NAME %in% flights$ORIGIN_CITY_NAME)` sets the frequency to the total number of rows in carrierDelayed for all values, I'm guessing these aren't the correct arguments